# For what primes $p$ is the mod 2 polynomial $(x^p-1)/(x-1)$ irreducible? Are there simple criteria?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

The polynomial $(x^p-1)/(x-1)$ is irreducible over the integers exactly when $p$ is a prime. But it is only sometimes irreducible when considered as a polynomial over $Z_2$. Are there any simple criteria for $p$ to tell when that happens? What about for other prime moduli besides 2?

Comment: Seems that for $p>2$ , the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2$ if and only if the order of $2$ modulo $p$ is $p-1$ (in other words if $2$ is a primitive root mod $p$). Can someone approve this ? A similar criterion should hold for other moduli.

Comment: @Peter: yes, that's correct, and the generalization to cyclotomic polynomials over a finite field holds.

Comment: I want to add the following. [Artin's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) predicts that irreducibility holds for a certain percentage of primes. IIRC it is unknown whether the polynomial remains irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ for infinitely primes $p$, but it **IS KNOWN** that for infinitely many primes $p$ the polynomial remains irreducible over at least one of $\Bbb{Z}_2$, $\Bbb{Z}_3$, $\Bbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: D'oh, my recollection is confirmed by scrolling down that WP-page :-)